# Highcharts Column Chart - zero values in IE

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts and I have noticed that in IE 8 it seems to draw a small bar for zero values which it doesnt do in Firefox. I am also using the grouped categories plugin from the black label github page.

How do I get highcharts to be consistent and just not draw any bar in IE for zero values?

Comment: Could you supply live demo ?

Comment: I could provide all of the json that I am using to generate the chart if that would help at all?

Comment: Without any example / data it is difficult to predict what is wrong.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. This is the json I return to the browser to render the chart. In IE for all of the zero values there is a tiny bar drawn and this is confusing because zero starts at the line so it appears as if it would be slightly more than zero..

Comment: To be honest I'm not seeing your JSON

Comment: {"chart":{"renderTo":"container","type":"column"},"title":{"text":"HPV Results Grouped By: Age Range, Cytology Result","align":"left"},"subtitle":{"text":"Report Filtered By: No Filters Selected","align":"left"},"series":[{"name":"0 - 24","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"25 - 34","data":[0,0,120,12,18,6,9,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"35 - 49","data":[0,0,183,3,15,51,21,27,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"50 - 64","data":[0,0,51,12,6,15,21,15,6,9,0,3,3,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"65+","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},

Comment: {"name":"Unknown Range","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}],"xAxis":{"categories":[{"name":"0","categories":null},{"name":"1","categories":null},{"name":"2","categories":null},{"name":"3","categories":null},{"name":"4","categories":null},{"name":"5","categories":null},{"name":"6","categories":null},{"name":"7","categories":null},{"name":"8","categories":null},{"name":"9","categories":null},

Comment: {"name":"B","categories":null},{"name":"E","categories":null},{"name":"G","categories":null},{"name":"M","categories":null},{"name":"N","categories":null},{"name":"Px","categories":null},{"name":"X","categories":null}],"min":null,"lineColor":"#003350","lineWidth":2},"yAxis":{"lineColor":"#003350","lineWidth":2,"gridLineColor":"#003350","alternateGridColor":"#EEEEEE"},"exporting":{"enabled":false},"scrollBar":{"enabled":true}}

Comment: Sorry there were limits on the amount of characters and then timer limits when I tried to break the json up so I had to wait between pastes.